# FolderBrowserDialog in VB does not expand directory tree

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use a FolderBrowserDialog (in VB Express 2013) to allow a user to select a working directory. I have found many examples (all very similar) but things do not seem to work.
My code:

```
Sub TestIt()  
    Dim dlgChooseFolder As New FolderBrowserDialog  
    Dim dr As DialogResult  
    dlgchoosefolder.Description = _  
        "Select the directory that you want to use As the default."  

    ' Default to the My Documents folder.   
    dlgChooseFolder.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal  
    'dlgChooseFolder.SelectedPath = "c:\users\mary\Documents\WebStuff"  
    dr = dlgChooseFolder.ShowDialog  
    If (dr = DialogResult.OK) Then  
        Debug.Print("dr = OK" & vbCrLf & dlgChooseFolder.SelectedPath)  
    Else  
        Debug.Print("dr <> OK")  
    End If  
End Sub
```

The dialog displays, but the only entry in the tree is "Documents", and it does not expand to display its sub-directories. Even when I explicitly set the SelectedPath property before I ShowDialog, it always resets to the RootFolder.

Here is the dialog box as displayed:[FolderBrowserDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqXr2.png)

Can anyone help? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Mable

Comment: What happens if you remove the `dlgChooseFolder.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` line?

Comment: I just tried the same thing on three different machines and I see the same behaviour. The first two had had the location of the Documents folder changed so I thought that might be the issue but the third did not and behaved the same way. The Music folder did the same thing too, but the level above, i.e. `SpecialFolder.UserProfile` worked as it should. I wonder whether this is a Windows 10 issue. I don't recall seeing this on older versions but I'm not sure that I ever set the `RootFolder` to Documents before either.

Comment: RootFolder defaults to the desktop if it is not explicitly set. The directory tree works properly, but allows the user to select folders I do not want them to select.  You may be on to something with the Windows 10 question. This code worked properly a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I am 95% sure this is a Windows 10 problem. I have set .RootFolder to all 59 members of the Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration. Some of them display a directory tree; many do not. Neither MyDocuments nor Personal work. The value that works best for my purposes is MyComputer. The other alternative seems to be "roll your own".